# ¿Cómo traducir "pet peeves" al español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Hoy he tenido la suerte de charlar con uno de los vicepresidentes de mi empresa, que nos ha dado algunas ideas sobre cosas a tener en cuenta en una presentación. Uno de los puntos que ha cubierto ha sido tener en cuenta los `pet-peeves` de tu audiencia (y era la primera vez que yo oía este término en inglés).

Él explicaba que, por ejemplo, su *pet-peeve* es que no soporta erratas, y si tienes una palabra mal escrita en tu presentación a él le va a cantar mucho. Advertía también que el CEO de la empresa tiene otra "pet-peeve" y es que no soporta que las *slides* o diapositivas que usas en una presentación no estén numeradas, porque le gusta referirse a ellas por el número, en plan "Vuelve a la diapositiva número 6" o "Enséñame otra vez la gráfica de la 8".

De ahí deduzco que "pet-peeves" puede ser desde `manías` hasta `preferencias personales`, pero la verdad es que solo tenía esos dos ejemplos para entender ese término, que era nuevo para mí.

Después lo he buscado en internet, pero sitios como [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=pet%20peeve) ofrecen un montón de posibilidades distintas (la mejor de ellas sería [*aversión*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4YtTXec), que me parece un poco fuerte para este contexto, ya que "aversión" se parece más a "fobia" que a "incomodidad/preferencia") que no parecen respaldar el uso que he visto que se hacía del término en mi reunión.

¿Cuál es una traducción apropiada para *pet-peeve*?

Comment: Veamos qué responden los demás. No sé si hay una sola palabra. Yo usaría la frase "lo que más me molesta es ..." o "no hay cosa que me moleste más que..." (y, en lengua bien coloquial, usaría "joder" en lugar de "molestar").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El verbo *to peeve* significa principalmente *<sup>molestar</sup>/<sub>irritar</sub>* , con fuerte toques de *<sup>enfadar</sup>/<sub>enojar</sub>* (especialmente cuando se usa como participio: *to be peeved* --> *quedar enfadado por algo que te molesta*).  Pero un *pet-peeve* es algo muy personal (por eso lo de *pet*, algo que te pertenece a ti) y no suele molestar a otros, o por lo menos no les molesta al punto de enojo.

Mencionas manía que no me parece completamente mal:

> **manía**
>   **1.** *f.* Preocupación caprichosa y a veces extravagante por un tema o cosa determinados. || **2.** *f.* Afición exagerada por alguien o algo. […] || **3.** *f. coloq.* **ojeriza** […]

Lo que pasa es que *manía* no indica, por sí solo, una aversión maniaca (otra palabra que mencionas) y puede ser una afición, como indica la 2.ª acepción.  No obstante, como nos indica la 3.ª acepción, puede implicar enojo —aunque es cierto que algo ojeriza suele ser hacia una persona y un *pet-peeve* suele ser hacia una acción—.

Pensando en los verbos que ya mencioné que caben en el significado de *to peeve*, lo que más me llega a la menta es *fastidiar*, que parece englobar estos conceptos bastante bien:

> **fastidiar**
>   **1.** *tr.* Enfadar, disgustar o ser molesto a alguien. || **2.** *tr.* coloq. Ocasionar daño material o moral. || **3.** *tr. desus.* Causar asco o hastío. *Era u. t. c. prnl.* […]

Entonces, lo que necesitaríamos es algo *que nos fastidie (personalmente)*, y desafortunadamente, aunque *fastidio* existe, es el sentimiento causado, y no lo que fastidia.

De ahí, buscando en un diccionario de sinónimos, para ver si podría encontrar una palabra sinónima que tenga un sustantivo que signifique la acción que X (en vez del sentimiento provocado de X), encontré algunos que parecen encajar más o menos bien con la idea:

> **joroba<sup>1</sup>**
>   **1.** *f.* Giba, corcova, chepa. || **3.** *f. coloq.* Impertinencia y molestia enfadosa.
>
> **joroba<sup>2</sup>**
>   **1.** *interj. eufem. coloq.* U. para expresar irritación, enfado, asombro, etc.
>
> **hastío**
>   **1.** *m.* Repugnancia a la comida. || **2.** *m.* **disgusto** (‖ fastidio).
>
> **desazonar**
>   **2.** *tr.* Disgustar, enfadar, desabrir el ánimo. *U. t. c. prnl.*
>
> **jeringar**
>   **3.** *tr. coloq.* Molestar o enfadar. *U. t. c. prnl.*

De todas estas, los que más me parecen tener algo que ver con un *pet-peeve* o el verbo *to peeve* son *jeringar* y *joroba*.  Los significados de *joroba* me parecen más coincidentes, pero (que sepa yo) no hay una palabra establecida para indicar algo que jorobe.  Una *jorobadura* es la acción en sí, *jorobeta* es el resultado de ser jorobado, y *joroba* es el sentimiento de estar jorobeta/jorobado.  En tal caso, quizás se le podría aplicar un sufijo agente como *<sup>-dor</sup>/<sub>-nte</sub>* pero no creo que goce de gran uso en esta forma.

Con *jeringar*, es posible que, por la acepción de *jeringa* se podría usar tal cual, aunque normalmente parece referir al sentimiento (~joroba), pero sí está registrado *jeringador<sub>/a</sub>* que se puede usar como sustantivo.

En todo caso, llamarlo un *jeringador* o *jorobador* tampoco creo que capture bien el efecto (si bien captura la idea).  Quizás mejor sería llamarlo un *fastídiame* pero tal vez puedas pensar en otra forma que ya existe para indicar tal tipo de cosa.

Comment: (no creo haber respondido muy bien, pero lo empecé como un comentario y bueno... ya sabéis que la brevedad no es un don que poseo)

Comment: Al contrario, muy completa y como siempre muy didáctica e instructiva. Yo estaba mentalmente atascado y no me salía nada mejor que "manía". Sólo por "jorobadura" y "jorobeta" ya tenía que darte el +1, pero el resto de sinónimos son también geniales.

Comment: @diego yo sigo apostando por llamarlo un *fastídiame*: Sabes que el no poner tildes es mi mayor (o peor) fastídiame. Unos fastídiame comunes son hablar con comida en la boca, cantar con auriculares puestos, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Para aportar otra, yo uso mucho la palabra

> [**neura**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QRRqVTJ)
>
> *Acort. de neurastenia.*
>
> **1**. adj. coloq. Dicho de una persona: Muy nerviosa, obsesiva y maniática. U. t. c. s.
>
> **2.** f. coloq. **manía** (‖ preocupación extravagante). Tiene muchas fobias y neuras.
>
> **3.** f. coloq. **nerviosismo**. Siempre que le da la neura, se marcha.

Y para ser justos con lo de "pet", mascota, yo le agregaría *favorita* o *preferida*:

> Neura favorita

La mía son los silbidos, sorry.

Comment: Me gusta esta opción. *Neura* da un toque cariñoso similar al que aporta en inglés la palabra *pet*. Voy a probar a usar *neura favorita* a partir de ahora.

Answer (score 2):

La diferencia entre una preferencia personal y una manía es que las segundas te causan irritación si alguien hace algo que va en contra de tu manía. Por ejemplo: si tu preferencia personal es no cometer faltas de ortografía, tú procurarás no cometerlas pero si otros las cometen, pues lo entenderás y no le darás mayor importancia. Pero si es una manía, las faltas de ortografía de los demás te causarán irritación.

En el *Urban dictionary* la expresión *[pet peeve](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pet%20peeve)* viene definida así:

> An irritating experience caused by others in which you cannot control.

Eso se parece bastante al término *[manía](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OD12Tcb)* ("preocupación caprichosa y a veces extravagante por un tema o cosa determinados"), la diferencia es que la manía parece ser lo que hace que una experiencia te cause irritación, y un *pet peeve* es la experiencia en sí que te causa dicha irritación. De hecho, es posible que algo te ocasione un *pet peeve* sin necesidad de tener una manía por el tema que te ha causado la experiencia irritante. En todo caso, no veo mal el traducir *pet peeve* por *manía*.

Otra opción es que se pueda traducir como *[disgusto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Dv4ezVh)*:

> 1. m. Sentimiento, pesadumbre e inquietud causados por un accidente o una contrariedad.
> 2. m. Fastidio, tedio o enfado que causa alguien o algo.

Sobre todo esta segunda definición parece encajar bastante con la definición del *Urban dictionary*. O si no directamente, dando un rodeo: un *pet peeve* sería un *motivo de disgusto*.

Como alternativa, y siendo un poco laxos, igual se podría traducir *pet peeves* por *malos rollos*. ¿Se podría decir que una presentación llena de faltas de ortografía te da *mal rollo*?